# Why "present continuous tense" instead of "present simple"

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Could you please help me with this question?

I ———— English at evening classes this year.

(A) learn (B) am learning (C) have learning (D) was learnt

Answer says B but I think answer should be option A.

Please help.

Comment: What's the source where you found this question?  Depending on the context, either A or B can be correct.  If your textbook says only B is correct, then it might not be very reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple present tense is used to describe actions which happen regularly (for example, every day or every week.)

**Example: I go to school every day.** (*'every day'* is a habit.)

The present continuous tense is used to describe something which is going on right now (but it will stop in the future.)

**Example: It is raining outside.** (the rain is temporary, and will most likely stop soon.)

In your example, "I _______ English at evening classes this year." - 'this year' is a temporary state, therefore present continuous is used.

[This page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous) might be worth further reading.

Answer (score 1):

I **am learning**English at evening classes this year.
Since there is the adjunct **this year**, it means an action happening in this period which requires the use of present continuous.